# set tempofatcor for MIDI

Tags: java

I couldn't make the MIDI player take effect with new value other than 1.0, what wrong with the code? No error was shown on the console.

```
vaTempo = Pattern.compile("tempo").matcher(f).replaceFirst("");
            float ff = Float.valueOf(vaTempo.trim()).floatValue();
            if (sequencer != null && sequencer.isOpen()) {
                System.out.println("TemopoChange: "+ff);
                sequencer.setTempoFactor(ff);
            }
```

Comment: What is `Pattern.compile("tempo")` supposed to do?

Comment: This is a regex function that match tempo and replace with ""

Comment: Found my mistake and has resolve my issue.

Comment: @user: then you should either post your own answer stating how you solved the problem (and accept your own answer when you can), or delete the question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might have meant to write `Pattern.compile(tempo)` instead of `Pattern.compile("tempo")`. Do you have a `tempo` string that you're tring to extract a `float` from?

Comment: Found my mistake, cannot accept negative value, switch to 0.1-0.9 range.